# Substituting with regex in python does not work

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text

I have a long string containing different dummy dates and want to replace a part of a mail multiple times with different date values in my dummy_date string. The below code return 1 result substituted with the last date of dummy_date. How can I do that for all date values in the dummy_date? I cannot iterate over string. Also, when I write my string to .txt file, just last item is written.

```
dummy_dates= "14 B-Laycan Dec I-Laycan 2012 I-Laycan
15 B-Laycan Jan I-Laycan 2013 I-Laycan
16 B-Laycan Feb I-Laycan 2014 I-Laycan
17 B-Laycan Mar I-Laycan 2014 I-Laycan"

dummy1= re.sub(r"((\d{1,2})([\w\W]{1,10})( B-Laycan)+(([\w\W]{1,10}( I-Laycan)+){0,6}))", dummy_dates ,mail)
```

Comment: You want to replace 'I-Laycan' with one date and 'B-Laycan' with (potentially) a different date?

Comment: I want to replace for example "14 B-Laycan Dec I-Laycan 2012 I-Laycan" with its' similar pattern in mail.

Comment: Please give us an example. What would "14 B-Laycan Dec I-Laycan 2012 I-Laycan" become?

Comment: It mean "14 Dec 2012". so, I want to replace the date in email different dummy dates, like "14 Dec 2012"

Comment: You don't need a regex for this; two replaces will do it. `dummy_dates.replace('I-Laycan', 'Dec 2012').replace('B-Laycan', 'something else')`

Comment: @NajmeRastegar: What is `mail` like? Please post the input text and required output and why you need that output and not another. Right now, the question is unclear.